# Replace and Split Multiple \n

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string that I want to split on the "\n" but I need to remove/replace all of the occurances of multiple "\n\n";

Here is my sample string:

```
"\n01:05 PM\n901\nNew York Mets \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n+125\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

So that I end up with an array like 
1:05 PM 
901
New York Mets
+125

I've tried,

```
 string adjRow = row.InnerText.Replace("\n", "");
```

Is there a single Regex Pattern that will work?

Added the following and seems to work.

```
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
                    Regex regex = new Regex("[\n]{2,}", options);
                    string adjRow = regex.Replace(tempRow, "\n");
```

Here is the result,

> "\n01:05 PM\n901\nNew York Mets \n \n+128\n \nOv\n8½\n-113\no\n"

Comment: Replace `\n+` with `\n`

Comment: Actually, `\n{2,}` makes more sense, why match a single newline if you need to keep it as is.

Comment: I'm not following.  You want _"an array like 1:05 PM 901 New York Mets +125"_ and you want to _"split on the '\n'"_.  I don't see any array, and I don't see you "splitting".  My take... do it in two passes.  Replace every "\n" with a space, and then use a regex to replace occurrences of multiple spaces with a single space.

Comment: Ignoring the regex, you can use `Split(new string[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmpty)`. (I'm not near a computer right now so maybe you have to change some stuff)